# rowversion or doc version in mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, rowversion, database

What would be a sound way to do row versioning in mongodb. Sql server had a rowversion field that got automatically incremented when a row got updated based on a relative time sql server tracked within the database. Wondering what a good scheme in mongo for the same would look like?

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin support for row versioning in MongoDB such as the kind you mention for SQL server.

However, you could always add a version field to your documents. Then, whenever you wanted to update the document you would use the [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#dbcmd.findAndModify) command to do so atomically. Each such atomic update would also have to increment the document version number. For example, suppose the collection `foo` contained the document `{ "_id" : "example", "a" : 3, "version" : 1 }`. The following atomically sets `a` field to 9 and increments the version number using the mongo shell:

```
db.foo.findAndModify({
  query: {_id: "example"},
  update: {$set: {a: 9}, $inc: {version: 1}}
});
```

By default, the document returned is the state of the document *before* the update was applied. To return the modified version of the document, add `new: true` to the query.

Note that if you do not need a copy of the modified document, then you can simply use update instead of findAndModify (i.e. findAndModify is good for updating and returning a document in one atomic step, otherwise update is just as good).